# aws events put-targets CLI result into Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 118 (char 117)"

Tags: ansible, aws-cli

I reformulate the question now for better understanding now

Comment: You have a lot of snippets, but without knowing what's in `xxx` or `cc` no one can possibly help you. Also, when you have type confusion (as is clearly happening to you), `- debug: var=xxx` and `var=cc` can go a long way toward showing you what is actually in those variables. Finally, it is very bad news to try and compose structured text (JSON, YAML, XML) with **string** templatating. Put together the `dict` you want, then only at the end convert it to JSON with `| to_json` instead of `{{cc}}` which will merely to_string any old thing, introducing errors and causing you to ask SO questions

Comment: I Will create a new question regarding my issue now.